# What is the cable diameter of a single core of cat6 ?

Tags: cat6

What is the cable diameter of a single core of cat6 ? I can find the diameter and AWG of a whole cat6 cable (eg, 8 cores + outer insulation) but couldn't find the cable diameter of a single core of cat6.

Comment: It's defined (I guess) in ANSI/TIA-568.2-D - Balanced Twisted-Pair Telecommunications Cabling and Components. "This Standard specifies the mechanical and transmission requirements of category 3, 5e, 6, 6A, and 8 balanced twisted-pair copper cabling and components." Unfortunately this costs $1,773 :/

Comment: [AWG 26/7 == AWG 24 in Ethernet cable? - Page 1](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/awg-267-awg-24-in-ethernet-cable/)

Comment: @DavidPostill, you spent $1,773 just so you could answer this question?  Wow!  That's dedication!  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 I didn't spend the money. I found another link which seems to answer the question ;)

Comment: @fixer1234 I've found a cheaper price ([$432.00](https://global.ihs.com/doc_detail.cfm?document_name=TIA%2D568%2E2&item_s_key=00339843&csf=TIA)) but I'm not going to pay that either :)

Comment: @DavidPostill, reminds me of the guy who jogged to work behind the bus to save money.  He started jogging behind a taxi to save even more.

Answer (score 0):

1.14 mm per [D-Link's specification](https://dlink-me.com/pdf/NCB-C6SGRYR-305.pdf), or one could simply measure a sample or two with a caliper